# Get table name from spark catalog

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataSourceV2Relation object and I would like to get the name of its table from spark catalog. `spark.catalog.listTables()` will list all the tables, but is there a way to get the specific table directly from the object?

Answer (score 0):

PySpark

```py
from pyspark.sql.catalog import Table

def get_t_object_by_name(t_name:str, db_name='default') -> Table:
  catalog_t_list = spark.catalog.listTables('default')
  return next((t for t in catalog_t_list if t.name == t_name), None)
```

Call as : `get_t_object_by_name('my_table_name')`

Result example : `Table(name='my_table_name', database='default', description=None, tableType='MANAGED', isTemporary=False)`

Table class definition : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Table.html